# Windows Server 2012 "User Logoff Notification for Customer Experience Improvement Program" events causing problems with backups

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, eventviewer

On this Windows Server 2012 server every time a backup fails, there is an event in event viewer (Windows Logs > System) at the very same second the backup file stops been written to.

"User Logoff Notification for Customer Experience Improvement Program"
Event ID: 7002   User: SYSTEM

The thing is the Customer Experience Improvement program is disabled on this server but these events still happen anyway.

Comment: It may take a while to understand, but the "User Logoff Notification for Customer Experience Improvement Program"is merely a misleading symptom. If you want help with the actual problem, there needs to be actionable information here, not conjecture.